# how to set a unmovable map marker in react native

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, react-native, apple-maps

does any one know how to set up an unmovable marker in React Native?
The marker should be placed in the middle of the view and user can only move the map to change location, similar to uber's pick up point marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use this function *onRegionChange* .

Here is a simple example that I just create.

https://rnplay.org/apps/v03lIQ